# How to manually end stream created by Table#createReadStream()?

Tags: node.js, streaming, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to process data from BigTable table in a stream, but end stream early.
I am using this code for Node.js (slightly modified https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/blob/master/samples/document-snippets/table.js#L215):

```
const stream = new BigTable({projectId, keyFilename})
  .instance(instanceId)
  .table(tableName)
  .createReadStream();
stream.on('data', () => {
  stream.end();
});
stream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('end');
  stream.destroy();
});
stream.on('close', () => {
  console.log('close');
});
```

Output is:

```
end
close
```

But the process is not yet finished.
So, i believe that some resources are not closed.
How should i stop stream and close relevant resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it might be a bug in the client library. I re-posted your question as a github issue:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/issues/506

Update: this has since been fixed, https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/pull/507. Client version https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable/tree/release-v2.0.4 and later contain the fix.